# Hibernate PostUpdateEventListener is not giving old values state if saveorUpdate or update is used

Tags: spring, hibernate, post-update

We are implementing the activity log for our application. we decided to go with the approach of capture the hibernate postupdateevent listeners and capture the old values and new values and update our activity log. The approach works wherever we have merge operation. But when we used saveorupdate or update we were not getting the old values.

```
PostUpdateEvent postUpdateEvent = (PostUpdateEvent) event;
                Field[] fields = postUpdateEvent.getEntity().getClass().getDeclaredFields();
                String[] propertyNames = postUpdateEvent.getPersister().getEntityMetamodel().getPropertyNames();
                Object[] newStates = postUpdateEvent.getState();
                Object[] oldStates = postUpdateEvent.getOldState();
```

Edits: 
As part of this there are few queries, on the gaps i have in my understanding.
With respect to hibernate, there are three states:
1.Transient
2.Persistant
3.Detached

If we create a new object, it is transient state. Now when we do update or saveorupdate or merge with the hibernate session, then the object becomes persistent.

In this scenario, if we use hibernate postupdateevent to capture the updates, we are getting the old values only when we use merge and we dont get the values when we use update, or saveorupdate.
My understanding was saveorupdate also does get call to determine if it is insert or update, in such cases i was expecting it to give old values in hibernate postupdate event when we do saveorupdate similar to what we get when we do merge.
But we dont get for saveorupdate and update calls, we just get the old values for merge.

It sounds like the postupdateevent listener if we use for audit logs, with saveorupdate or update, it wont give us the old values.

Am i missing something here?

Comment: Can you post your PostUpdateEvent listener code, to see how are you implementing the event listener and registering in hibernate configuration

Comment: @Siva, could you please check how your PostUpdateEvent is getting created in all the three use cases. That will help you understand why it is happening. In Merge method, we deal with two objects whereas in SaveOrUpdate/update method we deal with only one object

Comment: @kareless I am getting the events captured in PostUpdate Event for all the three type of update operation - merge, save and saveorupdate

Comment: @vkrishna17 my understanding is saveorupdate is also dealing with an object fetched from the DB to make a call if we need to save or do an update

Comment: @Siva, saveOrUpdate/update methods does not return any object. though they deal with the objects which were passed to them as an argument but merge method deal with two objects, one is passed and one is returned. So it might be the case PostUpdateEvent might be getting generated with the help of the returned object. So its better to check how it is getting constructed or generated.